# Pycharm check if .idea is valid

Tags: python, xml, pycharm

I wanted to know if there is a way of checking if a pycharm project is valid without running the GUI. Like when I try to open a project with invalid `workspace.xml` pycharm tells me:

> 23-Sep-20
> 17:02   Load Settings
> Cannot load settings from file 'C:\work\.idea\workspace.xml': ParseError at [row,col]:[173,3]
> Message: The element type "list" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".
> Please correct the file content

Is there maybe some library that pycharm provides that I can use? Something I could pass the `.idea` path to and throws an `Exception`/`returns` something.
Also, is it enough to just check if the `.xml` files in the `.idea` folder are valid? I was thinking of using `ElementTree` from `xml.etree`.